# Label alignment with display table cell

Tags: html, css

How can I get the labels to align horizontally in the following code:

```css
div {
  display: table;
  width: 200px;
}
div input,
div label {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>This is a label.</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>This is a label with a longer text.</label>
</div>
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/a7t3qnbg/1/

Edit: To be more clear: I can't change the fixed width and I want the labels to start on the same line as the checkbox and also be aligned horizontally (even after the line break).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `width: 100%` to the `div label`:

```css
div {
  display: table;
  width: 200px;
}
div input,
div label {
  display: table-cell;
}
div label {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>This is a label.</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>This is a label with a longer text.</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, simple solution. Can you explain to me why it doesn't work without setting the width?

Comment: If you don't set the `width` the browser will allocate 'spare' space amongst all the table-cells in a row.  The first row had spare space, and the browser allocated a bit to the table-cell containing the input.

Note: in your case each `div` creates its own `table`, they are **not** table-rows.  If you're actually trying to get table-ish layout, then you need a wrapper container with `table` layout, then change the `div`s to have `display: table-row` instead - then you can get rid of the `width: 100%` rule.

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be achieved using inline-block:

https://jsfiddle.net/a7t3qnbg/2/

```
div {
    width: auto;
}
div input, div label {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Let us know if you "have to" keep display:table as your layout.

Comment: I need the fixed with of 200px in this case. I also want both labels to start on the same line as the checkbox and be horizontally aligned (even after the line break).

Comment: You are going to encounter overflow issues with a fixed width of 200px if the label text is too big.

Answer (score 1):

You could use display: inline

```
div {
    display: table;
    width: 200px;
}
div input, div label {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the second label on the same alignment after the line break? It's below the checkbox with inline.

Comment: This should help (https://jsfiddle.net/a7t3qnbg/3/)
div input{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
div label {
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}

Comment: Thanks, setting the width on the label works. The inline-block property doesn't seem to be needed.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
width: auto;
}
div input, div label {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>This is a label.</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>This is a label with a longer text.</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use table property to align these labels. Even if you are using display as table, each inner div can be a table row

Answer (score 1):

You may just use `inline-block` for `label` as well *(default display for input)* and add `vertical-align`. `Input` **cannot** be displayed as `table-cell` nor inherit its specific properties.

`white-space` can be used to keep both element on same line.

```css
div {
   width: 200px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
div input,
div label {
  vertical-align:middle;/* or top or any other value that suits your needs */
  display:inline-block;/* usefull to label */
  white-space:normal;/* reset usefull to label */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>This is a label.</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>This is a label with a longer text.</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
div {
  display: table;
  width: 300px;
}
div input,
div label {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>This is a label.</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>This is a label with a longer text.</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add label in css and adjust the width you want

```css
div {
  display: table;
}
div input,
div label {
  display: table-cell;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>This is a label.</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>This is a label with a longer text.</label>
</div>
```